# codepen bootstrap mobile version wrong

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am getting the hang of bootstrap and so far its been awesome.

I tried to make my site from mobile first then up. But I guess I did something wrong or missed a step. When I view the page in [codepen](http://codepen.io/IrvingG/pen/adqaXg?editors=1100) where I built it it looks fine at any width. However, when I look at it through my iPhone or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irvgonz/eptqgLyq/) the works side looks totally wrong, they're not aligned and they're just all over the place. I wanted to have my items in 2 rows when the screen is xs or sm, and have three columns when the device is md and 4 columns when the device is lg. It seems that the sm,md,lg parts are working how they should but not the xs.

Also, when the viewport is small enough for the navbar is collapsed, how can I remove it once I click on something in it. Example I expand it and click projects, it goes to that section but it doesn't remove it.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navie" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navie">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#slide2">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide2">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide3">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide4">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <!----- SLIDES START --->
  <div class="jumbotron" id="slide1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slide2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
          <h1 class="text-center" id="about">About</h1>
          <p class="text-justify lead" id="aboutMe">
            Hi there! My name is Irving Gonzalez and I am a <b>Computer Science</b> graduate from <b>John Jay College of Criminal Justice</b>. Currently, I am working towards becoming a Full Stack Web Developer with the help of the curriculum from <b>freeCodeCamp</b>            as well as other self-taught web services. I have a passion for innovation, deviation, technology, and languages.

            <br>
            <br> Below are some of the projects I've made.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center">Works</h1>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="http://codepen.io/IrvingG/full/BjVvjb/" class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/9u8ytv.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Future Project">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Random Quotes</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="http://codepen.io/IrvingG/full/adRrvW/" class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2n21a8g.jpg" alt="Calculator" class="img-rounded">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Calculator</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="http://codepen.io/IrvingG/full/RrXKxK/" class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/r9k778.jpg" alt="Tribute" class="img-rounded">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Tribute</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a href="http://codepen.io/IrvingG/full/zqxLrE/" class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rmb98o.jpg" alt="Weather App" class="img-rounded">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Weather App</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project" class="img-rounded">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project" class="img-rounded">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project" class="img-rounded">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project" class="img-rounded">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="slide4">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4">
          <h1> CONTACT </h1>
          <p class="text-justify lead" id="contact">
            If you have any questions and/or comments, feel free to send me a message through any of these</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <a href="mailto:irv.jgonz@gmail.com" alt="irv.jgonz@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <a href="http://www.freecodecamp.com/irvgonz" alt="FreeCodeCamp" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-fire fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="http://github.com/irvgonz" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-3x"></i></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/irving" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-3x"></i></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/irving.gonzalez.1466" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x"></i></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="https://twitter.com/g0_irving" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
        <p>@ 2016 Irving Gonzalez</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the grid

The main problem here appears to be the lack of rows in your layout, or more specifically everything being in a single `<div class="row">`. Cols can handle collapsing most of the time, but in your case some of **your project names wrap to two lines when on a small enough viewport, causing the height of the containers to mismatch and throwing the layout off**. If you wrap every row of cols in a, well, row, this won't happen as the cols will have a direct container to align themselves with.

This could be fixed by messing with the headings and font-sizes, but really, the safest way to ensure your layout will keep its rows and cols is to explicitly define them instead of implying them like in your code.

### Additional note

Also, please put your section headings in a separate row/col. I'm talking about these parts:

```
...
<div id="slide3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="text-center">Works</h1>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
...
```

should be

```
...
<div id="slide3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">Works</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
...
```

You are somehow getting away with it in this case, but non-floated non-col elements should have their own row + full-width col or stay outside of rows with floated/col elements inside them, otherwise strange things can happen.

### Automatically collapse navbar on menu item click

This should be a separate question to keep with SO's single Q/A format - regardless, here is a solution to it: simply **emulate a click event on the navbar collapse button after a link has been clicked** (or you could use bootstrap's js methods but I'll leave that up to you).

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your suggestions. I was just confused as to how to go about it since I read some articles stating that if I wanted it that way I should just do it the way I did it. But i see your point and it makes sense about the collapsing and I think thats where I went wrong. So basically have x amount of rows I want depending on the screen size. Thank you this helped clarifying things.